# Explain this solution (sensitivity in optimization problems)?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Im looking at this question about duality in parametric problems:
[image]

And the proposed solution:
[image: line]

But I'm having trouble understanding what the solution means from the part where it starts talking about $\bar{\mu}$ being an optimal solution for the given problem. Why does the inequality hold?

Comment: Maybe it's not a good idea showing a solution without showing the problem...

Answer (score 1):

For the optimization problem
$$
\min_x f(x) \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad x \in X,\, g(x) \leq \bar{u}
$$
the [Lagrangian Dual Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)) is (as also explained in the provided solution)
$$
\max_\mu \left(\inf_{x \in X} f(x) + \mu^\top (g(x) - \bar{u})\right) \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad \mu \geq 0_r.
$$
The Lagrange multiplier $\bar{\mu}$ (of the original problem) is the optimal solution of this dual problem and hence for all $\mu \geq 0_r$ it holds that
$$
\inf_{x \in X} f(x) + \bar{\mu}^\top (g(x) - \bar{u}) \geq \inf_{x \in X} f(x) + \mu^\top (g(x) - \bar{u}).
$$In particular, this holds for $\mu = \tilde{\mu}$ and this is the argument used in the inequality in your provided solution.